# going up a level on a batch file directory

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, directory

I would like to use on a batch file a directory path that will change from people to people (it is inside a shared folder) and need to access a grand parent folder.

Right now I have the following:

```
"%CD%\R\R-3.4.2\bin\i386\R.exe" CMD BATCH "%CD%\run.R"
```

this works when R folder is on the same level as run.R file. But now I want to use the following structure:

```
-R
-dashboards/folder1/run.R
```

ie, R folder and dashboards folder are on the same level, and run.R is two levels below inside dashboards folder.

I'm asking for help to wright the correct directory to my R folder on the batch file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will give you a hint. A double `..` represents the parent folder.  So `..\..` represents the grandparent.

Comment: @Squashman It worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the code at the end of this answer in a Windows batch file it will run `run.R` provided that

- run.R is in the current directory and
- R is referenced in the registry (which would be the case for a default R install)

Optionally the user can specify the location of R by defining the R_HOME batch variable to point to the current version of R

```
set R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1
... now run batch file ...
```

They might want to do that if R is not in the registry or if they have multiple versions of R and don't want to use the currently registered one.  In the usual case that would not be necessary.

This effectively decouples the location of R and the location of run.R allowing it to be placed anywhere independently of the location of R.

```
@echo off
setlocal
if not defined R_HOME for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in (
    'reg query hklm\software\wow6432Node\r-core\r /v InstallPath 2^>NUL ^| findstr InstallPath'
    ) do set R_HOME=%%~b
"%R_HOME%\bin\R" BATCH run.R
```